# Android tasks and backstacks

Tags: android

I am trying to do something very simple, but yet it seems that its very complicated in Android

I have to support the following use cases

1. Launch app from launcher
2. Launch app from notifications

Assuming I have 3 activities (splash, main, details) and 2 notifications 
one tied each to main and details

Activity    Notification

Splash
Main       NotifMain
Details    NotifDetails

which show up in the notification shade I end up with the following scenarios

1. Launch app from launcher 
   Splash -> main
2. App is in foreground showing Main and user taps on NotifMain
   I see a second instance of main is launched even though main is configured as singleTask
3. App is in background and user taps on NotifMain
   Works as expected, and there is only one instance of Main
4. User is on Main, but taps on NotifDetails
   This causes NotifDetails to show, now, since in navigation because Details should take user back to Main, if I do that, I see Main twice
5. User is on Details, and taps on NotifMain
   I see Main, on which if I hit back it takes the user back to Details, on which if I hit back takes the user back to Main again.

This is very confusing and complicated. Is there a simple way to handle this scenario..

All i wish to do is.. that irrespective of my paths

if the usr taps on NotifMain, then there is only Main running for the application, with all other tasks cleared.

If the user taps of NotifDetail, then you have Main -> details in the application.